# Problema ao mostrar um "select count(*)" no PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
$result = $SQL->query("select count(*) AS codes_count from gamecodes WHERE gamecode='.$SQL->quote($gamecode).' AND alreadyused='N';")->fetch();
$counts = $result['codes_count'];
echo $counts;
```

Quando eu executo esta instrução SQL no banco de dados, o retorno é `1`.
Quando eu executo esta instrução SQL pelo PHP o retorno é `0`.

O que está errado?

Comment: Talvez usar o fetchOne(); e junta um var_dump do result

Comment: Como faço isso no PHP? Pesquisei no google e só deu resultado de Pyton

Comment: isso o que o var_dump ? var_dump($variavel);

Comment: nao funcionou, bugou tudo

Comment: bugar não buga ele printa um dump da variavel

Comment: é mais facil atualizar a pergunta com o retorno

Comment: e claro ja aproveita para colocar em portugues .... voce esta no stack brasil

Comment: string(1) "0" da isso

Comment: ta usando algum ORM ou como ta fazendo ?

Comment: é uma plataforma chamada Gesior, é um site de jogo. Ele usa PDO.

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode chamar um método dentro de uma string dessa forma pois o php pensa que uma propriedade está sendo acessada e um notice é gerado: `Notice: Undefined property Classe::$propriedade`

```
echo "$SQL->quote($gamecode) ...";
```

Sua consulta é interpretada como:

```
select count(*) AS codes_count from gamecodes WHERE gamecode='.(valor).' AND alreadyused='N';
```

Para corrigir isso, no caso use chaves em volta do método:

```
 echo "{$SQL->quote($gamecode)} ...";
```

Ou concatene  chamada:

```
echo 'algo '. $SQL->quote($gamecode) . ' mais alguma coisa';
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zq4s-5jkr)**

[Strings - manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php)